# How to get Session Id In C#

Tags: c#, sessionid

what is the correct way to get session id in C#

```
String sessionId ;
sessionId = Session.SessionID;
```

or

```
 string sessionId = Request["http_cookie"];
 sessionId = sessionId.Substring(sessionId.Length - 24);
```

Actually i am totally new to C# and just jumped in a project where i find the second code and by Google i found the first code so anyone please tell me what is the actual code to be used

Comment: thanks Kjartan for correcting typo

Answer (score 40, accepted):

correct way is:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID
```

Comment: What if multiple sessions are running?

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722171/asp-net-multiple-session-objects-in-a-single-application

Comment: In MVC, inside Controller, use full path due to inheritance Controller Base
string sesionID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh does not exist multi-session (as .net object) ...only multy-threads, every thread with own session id.