# Controller.Session and HttpContext.Current.Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Are `Controller.Session` and `HttpContext.Current.Session` the same objects? The matter is when I used `HttpContext` everything was OK but session data were lost in some minutes after putting values into `HttpContext.Current.Session` despite `<sessionState timeout="9999" />`.
But when I changed code to use `Controller.Session` everything appeared to be good.

Comment: check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940742/difference-between-session-and-httpcontext-current-session  and this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447611/why-are-there-two-incompatible-session-state-types-in-asp-net

Comment: @BurundukXP, thank you. Can't believe I didn't find them before