# how to get the session variable in many pages in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a field named username as the session variable. I have added a class which inherits the base page. Now I want the code to get the session variable in all the pages that the user moves through.

Please help me with the code.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/621620/19635

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the Session variable form all pages in the following way:

```
 var username = Session["Username"].ToString();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can access your current session variables using the Session object with an index, like

```
var myvalue = Session["mysessionvariable"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `session["username"]` to get the value. Then use this value as per your need

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property in a base class (which is inherited from Page class) which will encapsulate the Session variable and inherit that base class in every page you create

```
public string UserNameInSession 
{
    get 
           { 
              return HttpContextCurrent["UserNameSessionKey"].ToString();
           }
    set 
           { 
              HttpContextCurrent["UserNameSessionKey"] = value; 
           }
}
```

And then you can use this property either to set or get the Username from/to session like

```
string UserName = UserNameInSession; //Get it
UserNameInSession = string.Empty();//set it
```