# How to get session variables from a class file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, socialauth

Any one familiar with SocialAuth.NET ?? Kindly follow this link to checkout [SocialAuth.NET](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/) . Integrates seamlessly with a lot of providers such as Facebook, Twitter, Google etc.

Okay, enough introduction. Now, `SocialAuth.NET` stores everything in session. For e.g to get the Facebook User ID we call `SocialAuthUser.GetCurrentUser.GetProfile.ID` , since it is session based i get this error message **"Object Reference Not Set to an instance of an object"** when i try to call `SocialAuthUser.GetCurrentUser.GetProfile.ID` from a webservice or a class file.

Any idea how do i get it to work for me in a class file?? Any help immensely appreciated.

If this `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("NameHere")` is what i should use..what should go into the braces??

UPDATE: Kindly do not flag this question as **Duplicate** . I have seen this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621549/how-to-access-session-variables-from-any-class-in-asp-net), and not sure if this is what i should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented [IRequireSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx) for the classes where i was making these calls. This was to make the class aware of the current session state.

Comment: So this was the answer to your problem?  If so you might want to accept it.