# Make aspx not browsable by users

Tags: asp.net

I have a solution where one page requests the html from another page to build a PDF for download. How can I restrict direct browsing to the pdf-page when login Session variables are not accesible? Basically, I want pdf.aspx to only be accessible by the server.

```
private void DownloadPDF(string param)
{
byte[] bytes = PDFCreator.CreateFromURL("pdf.aspx?parameter=" + param);
//download bytes
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `web.config` restrict access to all users for the `pdf.aspx` page, like this:

```
<location path="pdf.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/> // deny all users
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Thx! Thought it might be as easy as that. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Authorization you can keep user's from finding the page via search engines etc with this: http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/prevent.html

And I typically just use a redirect:

```
if (condition) { Response.Redirect("http://www.microsoft.com/gohere/look.htm"); }
```

Comment: Thx, but it would not protect the page from users that know the url :)

Comment: The redirect will take care of that.

Comment: But I don't have access to any conditions(?) as I don't have access to any Session variables.

Comment: the "condition" is conditional. Omit the condition if necessary, e.g., `Response.Redirect("http://www.microsoft.com/gohere/look.htm");` in your code-behind (.aspx.cs).

Comment: Also, You can access session variables from any page or control using `Session["loginId"]` and from any class (e.g. from inside a class library), `using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["loginId"]`. (taken from this stackO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621549/how-to-access-session-variables-from-any-class-in-asp-net)).

Comment: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["mySessionVar"] from pdf.aspx returns null :(  Probably has something to do with the 3rd party PDF-component.

Comment: hmmm, that's odd. Not to be dismissive but that sounds like starting another StackOverflow question might help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Well first I'm not sure why the pdf creator must be another page, It could be a class that return the bytes of the pdf and could be invoked depending if the user is logged in :

```
private void DownloadPDF(string param)
{
  if(!System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return;
  //Call the class to create the pdf and download       
  //download bytes
}
```

But the way you can deny the access putting this in your web.config

```
<location path="Pdf.aspx">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
    </location>
```

But you can't access with the Response.Redirect you must use Server.Transfer.
I hope this help you

Comment: Assuming there is Authorization on the site.

Comment: Exactly or as you suggest use a Session variable