# I can't get a session's value and use it inside an if() statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms, app-code

I want to check the value of a session in my ASP.NET website (WebForms).
So what I have tried to do is:

```
// This file called 'Encryptor.cs' and is located under the 'App_Code' folder.

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public static class Encryptor
{
    public static bool CheckLoginStatus()
    { 
        bool LoginStatus = false;

        if ((string)Session["username"] == null)
        { 
             LoginStatus = true;
        }

        return LoginStatus;
    }
}
```

I keep getting this message: "The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context."
How do I fix it?

Comment: Check out this post: [How to access session variables from any class in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621549/how-to-access-session-variables-from-any-class-in-asp-net) The accepted answer is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the Session variable like this:

```
string username = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["username"];
```

The HttpContext resides in the `System.Web` namespace. You could either reference the namespace via a `using System.Web`, or go full namespace when accessing the session.

If you want to expand the usefulness of Session, and have strong typing on the variables, then you could opt in for this solution: [How to access session variables from any class in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621549/how-to-access-session-variables-from-any-class-in-asp-net)

Comment: But now it says: "The name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the current context."

|| edit: I should have added System.Web before what you've suggested. Now it works.

Comment: You need to reference the whole namespace. Either add `using System.Web` at the top, or `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["username"]`