# How to print values of C# session object

Tags: c#, session, object, httpcontext

I am saving some values in session as below.

```
List<MyEntity> MyVariable = <some values here>;
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MySession"] = MyVariable;
```

When I try to print MySession variable in Immediate Window then it displays following:

```
Count = 2
    [0]: {MyProject.Model.MyEntity}
    [1]: {MyProject.Model.MyEntity}
```

How do I print the values which are inside these indexes 0 and 1? I tried the following but it didn't work as it shows error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'":

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MySession"][0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast your value to the type you assigned, and apply the index on that :

```
((List<MyEntity>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MySession"])[0];
```

The Session only hold the generic type `Object` for all values, you have to cast them to the correct type each time you access it. To avoid casting at multiple places, you can create a wrapper class around Session, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/621620/2316200).

Comment: We have posted the same answer atthe same moment! :)

Comment: haha yes. Both of you are absolutely correct but Pierre-Luc Pineault posted it 9 seconds before you so I will have to accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast the session object to list, here is an example :

```
((List<MyEntity>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MySession"])[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this code:

```
using System.Web;

List<MyEntity> list = (List<MyEntity>)HttpContext.Current.Session["MySession"];

if (list != null)
{
    foreach (MyEntity item in list)
    {
        Response.Write(item.ToString());  // <-- you may want to override ToString to display the content
    }
}
```

You need to **cast** your session object, before you can access it as a list, because you can store all kind of `object`s in the session and by default an `object` has no indexer. Thence the error message.

After that you still somehow need to implement a way to **display** the content of the items. You could override the `ToString` method of your `MyEntity` class to do so.