# Creating sessions in classes

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to create a session in a class?

I am trying this in my authentication class:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["user"]["name"] = "firstname";
```

However I get this error:

> Error 342 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   'object'

Does anyone know why?

Comment: You probably mean this `HttpContext.Current.Session["user"]=''somevalue"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes can be added to a session. You could for example create a class:

```
public class User 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set ;}
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
}
```

Then store it in the session:

```
User user = new User() { FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "Doe" };
HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] = user;
```

Then to get the user from the session you would do:

```
User user = HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] as User;
string firstName = user.FirstName; // "Jon"
string lastName = user.LastName; // "Doe
```

Comment: If I am retrieving info from a data table and wanting to store the info from the datatable into the session separatly, would it be possible to store the row from the datatable into the session? Or is their a better alternative way for this?

Comment: I think technically it would be possible to store a DataRow in the session, however, I think creating a class to store the data is probably a better approach. Your method that returns the data could instead return the class. This will make it easier when you cast the session object back to the class.

Comment: So basically send the data retrieved from the DataRow into a class then send it back to a method to store into a session?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, yes. I'd use the DataRow to populate the class' properties and then return the class rather than return a DataRow or DataTable.

Comment: I just don't understand from your code how the User class, gets the values?

Comment: How it gets the values from the session? Or how it gets the values initially?

Comment: How it gets the values initially?

Comment: It doesn't. It's just a simple class. You tell it what the values are. So for example if your results are in a `DataRow` after creating an instance of the class you'd do `user.FirstName = dataRow["firstName"]`

Comment: Okay I understand, honestly thank you for your help! If I was to get the user from the session just like how you did in your code, would it appear as "JonDoe" in one string or would it be separated?

Comment: I updated my answer. The `Session` would contain the class `User`. You'd then access the properties like any other class.

Answer (score 3):

Sessions keys/values are not stored in [jagged arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx). They are accessed like a single dimension arrays:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] = "firstname";
```

---

Remember that sessions are stored per user at the server end so they could end up being expensive. Use them wisely.

Also consider, extracting session values in `Page` classes and then pass it on to your `class`. There is some related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/621722/961113)

Comment: So for each value I want to store in the session I would have to create another single dimensional array?

Comment: @Samrikan, not sure what you meant by *another signle dimensional array*, but here is what you need to do to store other value `HttpContext.Current.Session["SomeOtherValue"] = "Value";`

Comment: Yeah so if I wanted to store the surname I would have to do this again? Is it not possible to create a multi dimensional arrayed session at all?

Comment: @Samrikan, oh I get it, Store your object, instead of a single value. *(where your object would have properties for FirstName, LastName etc)* Read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)