# Is the following code safe in a multi-user web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

If not, is there a way to make it safe? Even though it populates the class members with what is in session isn't the public class static? That means the class/members could be bounced back and forth when multiple users are accessing the application at the same time...right? What am I missing?

Taken from [@M4N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19635/m4n) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/621620/158050

---

```
public class MySession
{
    // private constructor
    private MySession()
    {
      Property1 = "default value";
    }

    // Gets the current session.
    public static MySession Current
    {
      get
      {
        MySession session =
          (MySession)HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"];
        if (session == null)
        {
          session = new MySession();
          HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"] = session;
        }
        return session;
      }
    }

    // **** add your session properties here, e.g like this:
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
    public int LoginId { get; set; }
}
```

This class stores one instance of itself in the ASP.NET session and allows you to access your session properties in a type-safe way from any class, e.g like this:

```
int loginId = MySession.Current.LoginId;

string property1 = MySession.Current.Property1;
MySession.Current.Property1 = newValue;

DateTime myDate = MySession.Current.MyDate;
MySession.Current.MyDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: This might be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `isn't the public class static` - No. The getter `Current` is static, but the class most definitely is not. You would have one instance of `MySession` per session (or none at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though `MySession.Current` is static, it's not directly storing data. Instead, it's using `HttpContext.Current.Session` which is specific to each user's session and therefore it's as safe as the `HttpContext.Current.Session` object normally is.

Comment: Was able to test that out in my environment. Thank you.