# ASP.NET Session wrapper Session.Abandon() How to

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state, asp.net-session

I am using Session wrapper like described in answer here: [How to access session variables from any class in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621549/how-to-access-session-variables-from-any-class-in-asp-net)

But I don't know how to do Session.Clear() and Session.Abandon() using this principle.

My code:

```
public class AppSession
{
    // private constructor
    private AppSession()
    {
        CurUser = new UserHolder();
    }

    // Gets the current session.
    public static AppSession Current
    {
        get
        {
            AppSession session =
                (AppSession) HttpContext.Current.Session["__AppSession__"];
            if (session == null)
            {
                session = new AppSession();
                HttpContext.Current.Session["__AppSession__"] = session;
            }
            return session;
        }
    }

    // **** add your session properties here, e.g like this:

    // Current app user
    public UserHolder CurUser { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to abandon the actual session or just your AppSession? Becuase you can access the current session via HttpContext.Current.Session, and you can simply call Clear() or Abandon() on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do:

```
public class AppSession
{
   public void Clear()
   {
      //Remove items from the AppSession class
      //Update AppSession instance in HTTP Context session
      HttpContext.Current.Session["__AppSession__"] = this;
   }
```

Comment: Could you explain how calling "this" will clear the actual object? To mee it would seem that it just returns the instance with the get method in the wrapper class?