# How can I get session values in signal r

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I want to access session value on my hub class

My jquery code is as below

```
var con = $.connection.MyHub;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            con.server.send().done(function (data) {
                displayservices(data);    
            })
        })

con.client.addmessege = function (data) {
            displayservices(data);
            //alertSound();
        };
```

My hub class is as bellow

```
public Class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void send(string msg)
    {
      client.all.addmessage(msg)
    }
}
```

How can I access session value in my hub class

Comment: Please try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621549/how-to-access-session-variables-from-any-class-in-asp-net

Answer (score -3):

You can get the current session from `HttpContext`, like this:

```
var sessionVar = HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionVar"];
```

Comment: I know this is several months old, but this does not work.  SignalR vers 2 removed Session access from the Hub object.

Comment: @Wizaerd - In .Net Core 3.1, you can access the Session using Context.GetHttpContext().Session from inside the Hub class.