# Asp.net session property issue in a class

Tags: asp.net, session

I check session in a class. but Session property is null I mean not the variable session property.

normally we can check like this. session it's null or not

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Session["member_login"] !=null)
```

but
`**HttpContext.Current.Session**` This part of code line is null without string variable. Whats the problem I've searched stack overflow but I can't find like this problem

Webservices causes this problem but When we add this property over the webmethod we can solve it

```
[WebMethod (EnableSession = true)]
```

is this problem something like that?

[image]

[image]

check second image session property is null

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link

[How to access session variables from any class in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621549/how-to-access-session-variables-from-any-class-in-asp-net)

Comment: I know that. I said it on my first post. is this something like that?

and HttpContext.Current.Session this is giving me null so I cannot check HttpContext.Current.Session["member_login"] it's like webservice calling but it's a random class

Comment: Can you please add this runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" on your web.config
under
system.webServer>modules and try

Comment: it's not working can u check my first post I've edited. Check second picture.

Comment: Are u checking session in a class[Auth] library?

Comment: it's not a class library. it is a simple class

Comment: have you fixed this issue? If not, please paste entire code of that class after hiding sensitive info