# always return null error while get / set session variable in any c# asp.net classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have problem to get / set the Session variable inside c# classes, its working with MVC actions / asp.net forms but not working with other than Form /  MVC Controller classes.

i used this way

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["connectioncount"] = 6;

int a = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["connectioncount"];
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621549/how-to-access-session-variables-from-any-class-in-asp-net) i used this help

[image: Error]

> Problem: i need to set / get session variable value in 1 class other
>   than MVC controller class and also access this Session variable value
>   in Library / other 2 class. or i need a variable which will be used through
>   out the application but for each users it will have different values
>   and will clear / set to default when user will disconnect app. its web app

can any one help me, i find more solutions but have problem to use them.
i appreciate your valuable time.
thanks in advance.

Comment: where you use it? what kind of application it is? console app, windows app?

Comment: There are several things that can be `null` in that statement you have, could be the `.Current` or the `.Session` or the actual `.Session["...."]`, can you please make sure which one is null by decomposing the statement into it's parts in a watch window?

Comment: its a web application using asp.net MVC, but i need to access Session variable in my Library project and other classes in MVC but other than MVC controller classes.

Comment: what it means by several things, is this not a .Session only? @Ruskin

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` only has meaning inside an HTTP request lifecycle. Elsewhere it will always be `null`. Also, it's a really bad practice to access `HttpContext` outside the scope of an ASP.NET project (you mentioned *other* libraries). Please make sure you are trying to accessing it while a request is executed and not outside of it.

Comment: as i noticed now, HttpContext.Current is null, what other suggestion will be if i need to access Session in other classes.

Comment: The problem is not *where* you are trying to access to `Session`, but *when*. An `HttpContext` (and thus a `Session`) exists only **inside an HTTP request lifecycle**. To be clear: only when your code is executed due to a HTTP request from a client.

Comment: Bingo @adnan, so it wasn't the session but the fact that there is no `HttpContext`, is this call within an HttpRequest lifecycle as @federico suggested?

Comment: did you see the reference link, where i followed? is this correct or not @Federico Dipuma

Comment: reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621549/how-to-access-session-variables-from-any-class-in-asp-net

Comment: Your link explains *how* to access to a `Session`, but I do not believe you understood *when*. As already said is not *where* but *when*.

Comment: @Federico Dipuma, please can you tell me where i am wrong. thanks

Comment: I can't, because I do not know when are you calling the code, in which class, created how, and called in which context.

Comment: i need to set / get session variable value in 1 class other than MVC controller class and also access this Session variable value in Library 2 class. or i need a variable which will be used through out the application but for each users it will have different values and will clear / set to default when user will disconnect app,

Comment: @Federico Dipuma    more reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx