# Session accessed in my class file is not my session

Tags: .net, session

I have an application that is used by many people from many different workstations.  In this app, there are various user details being stored in the session when the user logs in.  These details are first stored within the global.asax file:

```
Sub Begin(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.AcquireRequestState

(various code that gets user details)

HttpContext.Current.Session("ID") = UserID

End Sub
```

I created a class file to more easily reference the session variables, call the Portal class. It looks like this (Portal.vb):

```
Public Class Portal
    Public Class User
        Public Shared ID As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Session("ID")
    End Class
End Class
```

In my application, on say, the default page (Default.aspx), I am referencing the user ID to do various things:

```
Sub Page_Load() Handles Me.Load
    Dim ID As Integer = Portal.User.ID

    (Do stuff with the ID)
End Sub
```

The problem that is happening is that, when someone logs in the first time for the day, the ID seen in the Default.aspx code is that of the first user.  But when the next person logs in, on a completely different work station, the ID seen in the Default.aspx code is still that of the first user.  I have confirmed that there is no issue with what IDs are being assigned to users.  I know for a fact that the global.asax file is putting the correct IDs in the session.  I have confirmed this by checking  session("ID").

For some reason, when accessing the session in the Class file (Portal.vb), the session being referenced is always that of the first person.  Does anyone know how this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared ID As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Session("ID")
```

This initializes the `ID` variable, once, with the value of the current session ID. Your code never updates this value in the `User` class. So you always get the session id of the first user.

To fix it, make it a method or a property that queries and returns the current session id.

Comment: So you are saying that I can't use a class structure for this?  And why would this session value be available to other computers at different times with different sessions?

Comment: ASP.NET is a server-side technology. This code runs in the server. The server knows about all users/machines connecting (or connected) to it. It's not that the user knows about it, it's that the server sets the value of `ID` only once and never updates it again. `Public Shared ID As Integer = ...` works just like `Public Shared ID As Integer = 0`. In both cases the variable's value is set once and never updated. You can use a class for this, you just need to fix the class to use the current user's session ID instead of having a fixed initial value.

Comment: This may sound dumb but, how do I do that?  I thought that when the class value is referenced, it is updated.  I see now, obviously it isn't.  What would I do to make it update?

Comment: I would make it to a property. A property is almost like a variable, but it can compute and return a different value each time it's used: https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgbgRgNALiCWwA+BJAtgBwPYCcYGcACAZQE98YBTNAWACh6AFAVwmHgGNCBhYAQ3xFGuGH2D1Ckwizace/QYQCq+SjglTNxABZ8clACaEASpT4GA8gDtgpaTiwY1MOygAiACgCUhAIJEUKyoAczUNTQjCAHFKGHDIhNMYZhwrQgAJGBgMbiwgygAPGAA6bhT9IOLiSkF4PI8AIncGr3iEwgBRKyMYuLp2rqNGByc8UnjB+QF8ekneafogA

Comment: See [Differences between Properties and Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/differences-between-properties-and-variables) for some details on why properties are a better solution for your problem than variables.

Comment: I have done that and it changed nothing. I do know that if I set the class field/property in the application code, not in the class, that the value does update.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out, for the most part.

TLDR (Too Long, Didn’t Read) answer: I needed to have the class properties utilize a Getter in a way I wasn’t familiar with.

Long Answer:

So in the Portal.vb class file, I first had class ‘fields’:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly UserID as Integer = HttpContext.Current.Session(“UserID”)
```

I chose fields over properties because I wanted these class values to be un-editable (ReadOnly), and class properties can’t be made un-editable (or so I thought).  In other words, the following code is not allowed:

```
Public Shared Const Property UserID as Integer = HttpContext.Current.Session(“UserID”)
```

The compiler doesn’t allow you to make the property constant (Const), nor does it allow read-only (ReadOnly), saying it doesn’t allow read-only auto-implementations of properties.  I thought that, perhaps, there was an issue between class fields and class properties so I tried converting all the fields to properties, leaving out the “Const” bit, just to see if it would work:

```
Public Shared Property UserID As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Session(“UserID”)
```

It had no effect.

"Omajid" suggested, above, that the class value was being set once and never being updated.  This would, in a way, explain the behavior.  I didn’t understand exactly how that would be as I thought that any time the class value is referenced, the code associated with it would execute, pulling the value from the session each time.  So then I thought that perhaps there is something different with how a Getter/Setter would work.  So I tried setting up the class properties with a Getter/Setter as I understood how to do it:

```
Private _userid As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Session(“UserID”)

Public Property UserID() As Integer
    Get
        Return _userid
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _userid = value
    End Set
End Property
```

This again had no effect.  And, Ironically enough, Visual Studio itself suggested that I should use an ‘auto property’, which simplified the whole code block to:

```
Public Property UserID() As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID")
```

This had no effect.  This is why I don’t really ever setup Getter/Setters; they don’t really seem necessary for the most part, since in VB there is this short-hand way.

A co-worker of mine sent me this article:

[How to access session variables from any class in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621549/how-to-access-session-variables-from-any-class-in-asp-net)

It had an example in it that had a different arrangement of a Getter, which made me think I could do something similar.  So I setup the class property like this:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property UserID As Boolean
    Get
        Return HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID")
    End Get
End Property
```

Bingo.  This did the trick.  It achieved both things I wanted: It updated the value for each user, and I was allowed to make the property read-only (ReadOnly) because there was no Set method.

So what I learned here is that class fields/properties are set once upon construction and not set again.  And in order to have a class property update each time it is referenced, it needs to be done through a Get method.

Since the real reason behind this question is that I needed to get the user's details to update to their own and not reference someone else's when calling the Portal class, this is the solution.  That said, one bit that still hasn’t been answered: How is it that class properties that are set in one user’s session are accessible by another user in another session?  This, to me, seems like a huge security risk.  But perhaps that’s only because I don’t understand the process.