# passing ISession in .Net 6 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http(.Features)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have been trying to pass the ISession from my ControllerBase to an underlying library.

I have a Class library, where I'd like to use the Session.

While the ControllerBase uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, then when using the Session in my class, as ISession, then it wants to install a nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.
This however this is another ISession, which e.g. lacks Get/SetString, I can only use Set/Get which works on byte arrays.
How do I get this right?

Another thing, I have 2 controllers - will they have the same session?

To me it looks like session data are lost when I use the other controller. Once I make a call to the other and back to the first, then my session data seem lost.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621549/how-to-access-session-variables-from-any-class-in-asp-net/621620#621620)

Comment: @XinranShen nope, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows

Use the Nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions`
It should be offered when using the static class `SessionExtensions`

In code when calling the Class Library, e.g.

```
public class MyClassLibrary: IDisposable
{
    public MyClassLibrary(ISession session)
    {
        var stored = SessionExtensions.GetString(session, "MyStorageName");
        if (stored == null)
            SessionExtensions.SetString(session, "MyStorageName", "Hello world");
```

Then it is only left to pass the `HttpContext.Session` from the Controller

As an additional hint, storing table data/arrays/lists, it can be done using `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyRowClass>>(stored)` and `JsonSerializer.Serialize()`